# How to access sessions across different servlets in Google Appengine/ Java

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, session, servlets

I read some where that, session attributes set under one context cannot be accessed by another context. I am assuming context here is a servlet.

I have a scenario here where I have a Appengine servlet class where I set a few session attribute as below.

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("username", username);
        session.setAttribute("password", password);

        System.out.println(session.getId());

        // response.getWriter().println("Done");
        response.sendRedirect("/dashboard.jsp");

    }
}
```

And as you can see, at the end I am redirecting to a different page. Where I am trying to get the session attribute. But it always returns null. 
dashboard.jsp is as below.

```
<%@ page import="com.bullbull.Employee" %>
<%@ page import="com.googlecode.objectify.Key" %>
<%@ page import="com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService" %>

<%


HttpSession sesn = request.getSession(true);

System.out.println(sesn.getAttribute("username"));

%>


<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
```

After login, it always prints null.

[image]

I know, I am going wrong understanding something somewhere. Please help !

Thank you !!

Comment: You are doing it right. It must be a configuration issue.

Comment: Hi @Manjunath - is this resolved? Otherwise, lets see this ....

Answer (score 0):

I think may be you missed to configure session in appengine-web.xml

`<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>`

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_Enabling_sessions

From the doc

`App Engine includes an implementation of sessions, using the servlet session interface. The implementation stores session data in the App Engine datastore for persistence, and also uses memcache for speed. As with most other servlet containers, the session attributes that are set with session.setAttribute() during the request are persisted at the end of the request.`

`This feature is off by default. To turn it on, add the following to appengine-web.xml:`

`<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>`

Comment: No, I have added that !!

Answer (score 0):

use requestDispatcher.forward instead of sendRedirect
http://www.coderanch.com/t/170618/java-Web-Component-OCEJWCD/certification/sendRedirect-requestdispatcher